Why would large activation energies give a large gradient of the rate constant?
I have read carefully this answer on SE, and there is a part I don't understand. SE exchange user said:

If you plot the Arrhenius equation (given in your text) vs temperature the slope of this gives the rate of change with temperature. With larger activation energies the slope gets larger.

When one actually derives the gradient of the rate constant: $$\displaystyle \frac{dk}{dT}=E_a\frac{A_0e^{-E_a/(RT)}}{RT^2}$$
One can clearly see that if $E_a$ is very large (let's say, for the sake of the argument, infinitely large), the gradient becomes equal to $0$. (In fact, the gradient is maximal for a certain positive $E_a$ value).
I don't understand then, why it is said in the mentioned answer that large $E_a$'s give rise to a large gradient.
It might very well be a quite basic math question, still I don't get it.
EDIT: Turns out that "large $E_a$ gives rise to large rate constant gradient" is true only until $E_a$ reaches $R T$ (temperature times the ideal gas constant). When $E_a$ is greater than $RT$ (at room temperature this limit is $\sim2kJ$) the sentence is no longer true.
Can anyone confirm me if I'm right?

Compare "infinitely large" with "almost infinitely large." The latter is infinitely smaller than the former. Doesn't make it small, though.

@Mithoron By "infinitely large", do you mean $\sim 2kJ$ ? (I've edited my post)

Perhaps it is easier to see if you  write the equation as $\displaystyle \frac{d\ln(k)}{dT}=\frac{E_a}{RT^2}$

It might very well be a quite basic logic question. If it's zero then it's the same speed - nothing changes with temp. If Ea is "infinitely large" then there's no reaction - nothing changes with temp. We're not interested with situation when nothing changes, just ones when it does - that's the mentioned scenario.
